# I can't consume a Bloc with Get it in Flutter

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-provider

I'm trying to consume a bloc with GetIt and I get this error:

> Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this BlocBuilder<GetUserProfileBloc, GetUserProfileState> Widget

> This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
> of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

Isn't GetIt supposed to consume the bloc without the Provider? How can I fix it?

Below is my code:

```
void main() {
  setupServiceLocator();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home:  MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  late GetUserProfileBloc bloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    bloc = sl.get<GetUserProfileBloc>();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: BlocBuilder<GetUserProfileBloc, GetUserProfileState>(builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is GetUserProfileInitialState) {
          return const Center(child: Text("initial"));
        } else if (state is GetUserProfileLoadingState) {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else if (state is GetUserProfileSuccessState) {
          return Center(child: Text(state.userProfile.toString()),);
        } else {
          return const Center(child: Text("sssssss"),);
        }
      }),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          bloc.add(GetUserProfileEvent());
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I never use that method. Try this instead, it works. If you struggle to get the context, then bind your scaffold with final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey(); put that into scaffold parameters Scaffold(key: scaffoldKey, );
With scaffoldKey, you can get your currentContext!

```
late PostBloc bloc;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  bloc = BlocProvider.of<PostBloc>(context);
}
```

or use this trick

```
@Override    
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MultiBlocProvider(
          providers: [
            BlocProvider(
                create: (context) => SomeServiceBloc()..add(CheckLocationOnEnd())),
    )], child .... );
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `getIt` does not mean that `BlocBuilder` can find the bloc in the build context. To fix this, use `getIt` to provide a bloc to the builder.

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  late GetUserProfileBloc bloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: BlocBuilder<GetUserProfileBloc, GetUserProfileState>(
      bloc: sl.get<GetUserProfileBloc>(),
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is GetUserProfileInitialState) {
          return const Center(child: Text("initial"));
        } else if (state is GetUserProfileLoadingState) {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else if (state is GetUserProfileSuccessState) {
          return Center(child: Text(state.userProfile.toString()),);
        } else {
          return const Center(child: Text("sssssss"),);
        }
      }),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          bloc.add(GetUserProfileEvent());
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```